# Where are the questions I favorite?

Tags: discussion, android-app

I'm using the Android App to access Stack Exchange and I have no idea where can I see questions I favorited by starring them⭐

Comment: @Catija I'm using application

Comment: @Catija Eee... Its really awkward. Thank you so much for for being kind and helpful.